# how to copy data from model to another model in Django after filtering?

Tags: python, django, django-models

here is the models:

```
class Rooms(models.Model):
    
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image=models.URLField()
    max_person=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    office=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cost=models.CharField(null=True,max_length=250)
    roomId=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Address= models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
    

class Available_Rooms(models.Model):
    users=models.ForeignKey(Rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image=models.URLField()
    max_person=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    office=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cost=models.CharField(null=True,max_length=250)
    roomId=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Address= models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

at model "rooms" there is 100 objects (rooms)

and what I want  filter it and list rooms that have maxperson = 4

```
availablity= Rooms.objects.filter(maxperson="4").all()
```

and want to to copy the rooms details to the other model "Available_Rooms"

any idea how that can be done?
many thanks in advance

Comment: It does not make sense to do that: usually you have some flag or another condition that determines if a room is available or not.

Comment: By duplicating data, you make it harder to manage that data: if the `name` of the room is for example updated, it will require all sorts of logic to update the related `Available_Rooms` record as well, making it thus (very) hard to keep the records in sync.

Answer (score 0):

> and want to to copy the rooms details to the other model `Available_Rooms`.

Please *don't*: it makes no sense to do that: you are introducing *data duplication*, which is an antipattern. This means that if you now want to change for example the `name` of a `Room`, you need to modify both the `Rooms` and the `Available_Rooms`. This will thus introduce a lot of extra logic to keep the rooms in sync.

What you can for example do is add a `BooleanField` that determines if the room is available, with:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.URLField()
    max_person = models.IntegerField()
    office = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cost = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    room_id = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Then you can for example make all rooms available that have as `max_person=4` with:

```
Room.objects.filter(max_person=4).update(available=True)
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Room` instead of <s>`Rooms`</s>.

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `room_id` instead of <s>`roomId`</s>.